# r rcp how to debug segfault on a mac with apple silicon

Tags: r, segmentation-fault, rcpp

Background. I have some R code that uses terra and Rcpp code on a Mac with Apple Silicon and runs over large climate data sets. The code runs through these data year by year. It fails randomly with a segfault. One bit of advice was to use valgrind but that doesn't run on recent Mac OS versions.

Update.
My solution was to transfer my code to a linux machine where I could run valgrind. Here's the code I ran in a terminal there.

```
R -d "valgrind -s" code/test_for_valgrind.R
```

To start off cd to the project directory.
R - run R at the command line - R needs to be installed

- d - run R in debug code
  "valgrind -s" - run valgrind with the s option. valgrind needs to be installed.

code/test_for_valgrind.R - run a simple R script in the code directory.

Hope this process description is useful to others.

Comment: It's not clear how anyone can help you without seeing the code and the data it's processing.

Comment: I am happy to share both code and data but we're talking about gigabytes and both R code using terra a c++ code. I can construct simple versions but the problems show up randomly as far as I can tell and after several megabytes have been processed.. And the last try of a smaller (but still big) version on linux worked fine. So that's why I asked for suggestions on what to try next. I suppose posting all of this in a box folder might be one way to go if anyone would like to take a look.

Comment: If you're getting a segfault my guess is there's a problem somewhere in your C++ code. Is that small enough to share?

Comment: I think so. I'll try adding it to the original question.

Comment: Its there now. I've attempted debugging with Rcout lines. Still scattered around. I've tried looking at the for loops and variable sizes. But I'm very much a novice. And had a lot of help to get to this point.

Comment: Apparently it didn't stay there. Must be some limit on the amount of text you can add.